# delphi XE 5 program unit

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, ide, delphi-xe5

How do I open the program unit in which the application initializes? There are changes I need to make.

Also, is there away to search all the units in the program besides the current unit displayed? Delphi 5 had a pop up window that allowed you to select.

Answer (score 5):

Each project is made up of a [single project file](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Programs_and_Units) (.dpr). This project files contains directions for building an application.

Use `Project - View Source` (go to the project manager, right click on the project, and select `View Source`) to display the project file for the current project.

[image]

You can also click on the project in the project manager and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, which is an overridden keystroke for the project manager that views the source of the selected project.

Although you can look and edit the Project File, in most cases, you'll let Delphi maintain the DPR file.

---

To search in all the units, you can use the "Search in all Files" command (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) which will open a dialog to specify other search criteria.